# Is it possible to distinguish traffic from different computers from behind a router?

Tags: router, ip-address, mac-address

The mac address would be that of the router, I presume. But could I distinguish the ip addresses of the computers behind the router, or could I only see a global ip address that belongs to the router?

Comment: The mac is thatthat of YOUR router - MAC addresses are not part of IP and do not get forwarded outside the physical segment, which normally ends at the next switch / ethernet port. SO, you do not even have a MAC address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) you can graph IP ID fields patterns to know how many distinct IP stacks are behind a NAT, but you may generally not be able to discover the IP behind the NATdevice.  [Here's](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html) a link to the page referencing it.

Comment: And what about dynamic ip addresses? Would scapy not be confused by that if they were completely random?

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: If the devices behind the router use a proxy, Scapy etc. will fail. If neither NAT nor a proxy is used, Scapy will not be needed, as you can identify the hosts by their IP.